# Google Sheet - IMPORTHTML - Error Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to pull the table from specific URL

Using: `IMPORTHTML("https://URLNAME","table",1)`

But I get the error:

> Error
> Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.

Can I bypass this issue by writing a custom script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing =ImportHTML with URLFetchApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790221/replacing-importhtml-with-urlfetchapp)